# Is it proper to write a full first name followed by an initial of the last name?

Tags: abbreviations, names, surnames

For example, if my name was John Smith, can I write it as “John S.”?

Also, if I want to start with the initial of the last name, how would I write it? Is it “S. John”?

I’m asking because I’m having my stethoscope engraved and I don’t know which one to use.

Comment: And why not J. Smith?

Comment: I’ve seen engravings for ownership in three styles:  J Smith,  Smith and JWS  (assuming middle initial is W)  there’s no right or wrong here. Just practicality.  It needs to fit in the space available, it needs to be pretty clear from the markings that it’s yours.  I wouldn’t use S. John   That’s not intuitive at all.

Comment: There is no rule of the language about this; it's up to you. Generally, one would use in such a case either *John Smith* or *J. Smith* (or perhaps just *Smith*) rather than *John S.* Writing one's name in the *John S.* format is usually done only in the settings in which other people use first names only, but one is concerned that, if one did that, one would be confused with another person of the same first name.

Answer (score 3):

I’d never encountered the “John S” abbreviation until about a couple of decades ago. These days, it is common in Australian schools.

My guess is that this is due to the preference for calling people by their first names instead of their surnames here. In Western contexts, it is more common to have several people with the same first name than to have several with the same surname. The first initial then serves as disambiguation.

When seeing a medical doctor professionally, it is still more common to address them as “Dr Smith” than the more casual/familiar “John” unless you are personal friends. By this convention, “Smith”, “John Smith” or “Dr Smith” would likely not raise any eyebrows. But “A stethoscope belonging to John S has just been delivered to the front desk” might portray you as a junior.

Nevertheless, it’s your stethoscope, so feel free to mark it with whatever you are happy to be called. The English language itself doesn’t require a particular convention for shortening names. In some parts of Asia, for example, you might be called “Dr John”. I find it a little jarring, but it’s a matter of culture rather than language at that point.

Comment: So if your name is Conran Alabama Lawrence, may you use the forename prefixed initialization Conran AL?

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal It's an informal convention, so I guess you could if you really wanted to, but it would be unusual.